# percentage function failing for calculator

Tags: javascript, string, floating-point, ecmascript-6

I require expert assistance with a calculator. It is js for angular, so no typescript, but it runs and gives me a calculator. However the percentage function only works for numbers under 100. If I do 4% of 900, I get 0.44. But if I do 10% of 100 I get 10.

Please help!

```
export class CalculatorComponent {


private runningTotal = 0;
private previousTotal = 0;
private currentOperator = null;


numberButtonClick(event) {


this.runningTotal = parseFloat('' + this.runningTotal + event.target.value);
  console.log(this.runningTotal)

}


changeSettings(operator) {
  this.previousTotal = this.runningTotal;
  this.runningTotal = 0;
  this.currentOperator = operator;
  console.log(this.currentOperator);
}


operativeButtonClick(event) {

    let operator = event.target.innerHTML;




    switch (operator) {
        case '=':
            this.makeCalculation();
            break;
        case '+':
            this.changeSettings(operator);
            break;
        case '-':
          this.changeSettings(operator);
            break;
        case '*':
          this.changeSettings(operator);
            break;
        case '/':
          this.changeSettings(operator);
            break;
        case '%':
            this.changeSettings(operator);
            break;
        case 'AC':
            this.runningTotal = 0;
            this.newTotal = true;
            break;
        case '.':
            this.runningTotal += ('' + '.');
            break;
    }


}



makeCalculation() {
    switch (this.currentOperator) {
        case '+':
            this.runningTotal += this.previousTotal;
            break;
        case '-':
            this.runningTotal = this.previousTotal - this.runningTotal;
            break;
        case '*':
            this.runningTotal *= this.previousTotal;
            break;
        case '/':
            this.runningTotal = this.previousTotal / this.runningTotal;
            break;
        case '%':
            this.runningTotal = ((this.previousTotal / this.runningTotal) * 100).toFixed(2);
            console.log(this.previousTotal)
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: create a working plunker.

Comment: shouldn't it be this..previousTotal * this.runnigTotal / 100 . You calculated 4 is 0.44% of 900

Comment: woops.... I have no rubber duck to talk to though. Thanks Turo, your absolutely right.